# Store Read buffer contents in string

Tags: c, string, io

I am trying to read the contents from a file, store it in a string, get that strings length, write that strings length, then write the contents of the file, to another file. To achieve an archive
# contents, where # is the length of contents.

So far this writes out some strange characters and writes out the the contents lines an extra time or too.
I need to keep reading if the contents exceeds the 1024 so I assume I write if len == 1024 then read again and concat that to data. I currently don't have that implemented, but wanted to get this working before I start making my file even larger.

```
int file2p = open(curFilePath, O_RDONLY, 0);
if(file2p == -1){
    printf("File open error.");
    exit(1);
}
char buffer[1024];
int len;
int dataLen;
char data[1024];                
while((len = read(file2p, buffer, 1024)) != 0){ 
    if(len == -1){
        printf("File open error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcat(data, strdup(buffer));   
    printf("data: %s", data);                   
}       
dataLen = strlen(data);
int lenLen = strlen(&dataLen);
write(filep, &dataLen, lenLen);
write(filep, ">", 1);
write(filep, data, dataLen);
//free(data); 
close(file2p);
```

Comment: `strlen(&dataLen)` is a no no. instead you should use `sizeof(int)`

Comment: I am assuming that these are text files, otherwise use `sizeof()` instead

Comment: Use sizeof even for the strings? I'm testing on txt files, but they can be binary files as well. Actually they just have to be a file. The program looks at all the files in a directory and archives each files name, permissions, and contents, into one file. From which then I have to re create the files.

Comment: if your files can be binary, then `strlen(data)` is no good either because binary data can contain `'\0'` character which will not give you the true length of the content, instead you will need to keep track of the number of characters read, so in the while loop add a line `dataLen += len;` and remove the `dataLen = strlen(data);` line

Comment: @JoeDF I don't think `sizeof(data)` would work because I believe that will only return the size of the pointer not the size of the amount of content that has been read.

Comment: I said this for BINARY FILES like png, exe, etc..

Comment: I think the when I duplicate the buffer, its duplicating all that extra space in the buffer, hence the weird symbols. if I wanted to grab only the string from the buffer, and not the extra space, how would I do that?

Comment: Also, I have all this in a while loop, which goes to the next file and does this same process, but in the write it has alot of the first files content in it. It's like the stuff in staying in the buffer.. how do I clear it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are leaking memory and overrunning buffers.  It's not cool.   Your `data` array is a fixed size: `strcat` won't make it larger.  And you can't guarantee the buffer is null-terminated, so `strdup` is out of the question.

You want something like this:

```
size_t dataLen = 0;
char *data = NULL;

while( (len = read(file2p, buffer, 1024)) != 0 ){ 
    if( len == -1 ) {
        perror( "Read failed" );
        exit(1);
    }

    data = realloc( data, dataLen + len );
    if( !data ) {
        printf( "Not enough contiguous memory\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    memcpy( &data[dataLen], buffer, len );
    dataLen += len;
}

write(filep, &dataLen, sizeof(dataLen));
write(filep, ">", 1);

if( data ) {
    write(filep, data, dataLen);
    free(data);
}
```

The above code is not the most efficient way to do it, but is simply an illustration based on your existing code.  It dynamically allocates and resizes the `data` buffer as necessary and uses `memcpy` to copy data between buffers.

Comment: This works, except dataLen gets written out as a bunch of strange symbols.

Comment: What did you expect?  You're writing a binary file.